# How to filter by price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

How to set the condition that it filtered < :check. 
I use gem 'ransack'

```
<%= search_form_for @search, id: 'catalog_filter' do |f| %>
   <%= f.search_field :check %>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def index
  @search = Restaurant.search(params[:q])
  @restaurants = @search.result.where(:publish => true, :status => 1)
end
```

Comment: can you give more detail on what you're trying to do. where are you putting the check, and what does that achieve

Comment: @max pleaner I do not understand how to write a condition in the model so that it looked for all that is less than the value of the field :check

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try

```
def index
  @search = Restaurant.search(params[:q])
  @restaurants = @search.result.where('publish = ? AND status = ? AND value < ?', true, 1, 800)
end
```

This should filter out values are that are less than 800

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= f.search_field :check_lteq, id: 'hidden' %>
```

`_lteq` looking for all that `<=` setpoint

```
#=> SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (`products`.`price` <= 1000)
```

`_gteq` looking for all that `>=` setpoint

```
# => "SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `items`.`price` >= 1000)"
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer rather than just posting code snippet

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)